# What is wrong with my jQuery code? I want a div to fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently started learning some jQuery. I want to fade in a div but nothing is happening. Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Everthing is linked so that's not the problem:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="inc/content_animate.js"></script>
```

content_animate is my .js file.
This is in it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

I want to fade in my .content div. Which is this:

```
<div class="content">
  <img src="img/design.svg">
  <h2>Design</h2>
  <p>I don't only program my websites. I also design my websites myself.</p>
  <a class="btn-content" href="projects.php">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance to everyone looking into this!

Comment: Do you hide the `.content` with css for example? Other than that you code should work [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h01gaqa/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code is fine, but if you dont hide your div initially, theres nothing to fade in, because its already showing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content').fadeIn('slow');
})
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <img src="img/design.svg">
  <h2>Design</h2>
  <p>I don't only program my websites. I also design my websites myself.</p>
  <a class="btn-content" href="projects.php">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This got it working! Thanks a lot. I will check the solution box when available.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".content").hide().fadeIn('fast')`